# Share file handle only to certain process and its childs

Tags: winapi, handle

I am creating file and usually setting share to 0 will not allow other processes to open handle to it but how can i make so that certain process (and its child proccesses) can open it too ?

Comment: Why do you even want that? I believe there're numerous other ways of achieving what you want, depending of what is your task.

Comment: @codeguard i defined my task in question already

Answer (score 0):

Using `CreateFile()` in each process, you cannot selectively choose which processes can access the file.  It is an all or none type of access.  What you would have to do instead is create the file and leave the handle open while you need the file, then have that source process use `DuplicateHandle()` to make a copy of that file handle for any specific process that needs access to the file, using any IPC mechanism you want to get the duplicate handle over to that process so it can use the file.

Comment: its not necessary to use CreateFile for me, it ok to use ntdll.dll apis